# Incompatibility convert DateTime between SQL Server 2012 and SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2019

I have a stored procedure running fine in SQL Server 2012, but when I run it in SQL Server 2019, I got this error message:

> The data types datetime and time are incompatible in the add operator.

This is the line of the error :

```
(CONVERT(datetime, shfts.Date) + SftpStartTime) AS SftStartDateTime,
CASE 
    WHEN ((CONVERT(datetime, shfts.Date) +SftpEndTime) 
          > (CONVERT(datetime, shfts.Date) + SftpStartTime))
```

Comment: You have the wrong concept for the "time" type. It does **not** represent so many hours, minutes, and seconds (aka .Net timespan) but rather represents a specific time of day... say, 8:30 in the morning. This is entirely different from 8 hours and 30 minutes. Adding 8:30 in the morning to a given DateTime is like adding "Apple" to "Blue".

Answer (score 2):

The following (`datetime + time`) does work in databases with compatibility level 100 (SQL Server 2008) but not in databases with later compatibility mode

```
SELECT {d '2000-01-01'} + CAST('11:59' AS time)
```

The execution plan for the above has an `CONVERT_IMPLICIT` from `time` to `datetime` that no longer happens here.

Explicitly casting the second operand to `datetime` (as below)  does work but is a bit icky and won't preserve all the precision possible of `time` (will lose any precision beyond milliseconds and round any millisecond component to `0`, `3` or `7`). Nonetheless this is the same as the 2008 compat would give you (and is unlikely to be a concern for shift start/end times).

It has the same results as adding a `timespan` to a `datetime` would (including possible rollover to next day if the `datetime` portion is not at midnight).

```
SELECT {d '2000-01-01'} + CAST(CAST('11:59' AS time) AS datetime)
```

A [less icky method](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51440/how-to-combine-date-and-time-to-datetime2-in-sql-server) is

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day,'19000101',{d '2000-01-01'}), CAST(CAST('11:59' AS time) AS DATETIME2(7)))
```